# How can I access a script variable from another script in Unity?

Tags: unity, 2d, architecture, software-engineering, gameobject

I'm creating a space shooter (think Space Invaders or Galaga) where the GameManager persists between scenes but the player and enemies don't. I need to access a boolean value from the player and enemies to define when and how the game should end. The `PlayerController` script contains a `playerDead` variable (attached to the `Player` `GameObject`) to tell the `GameManager` if the player has died and a `enemiesDead` variable to tell if all enemies have died.

Because the `GameManager` persists but the others don't, it loses the references when a new level is loaded. I tried to have the `GameManager` find the script references dynamically, to no avail. It always errors with `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` when a new level is loaded.

I've tried to get them with `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag()` and then using `GetComponent<ScriptName>()` to get the script and the variable in it. It compiles nicely and everything seems dandy, but then there's still no object reference. Am I just doing it wrong?

So how can I reference a script and get a value from it without even touching the Inspector?

EDIT:

Below is some code (everything else except the essential is scrapped) from the `GameManager` script, I tried to use `Object.FindObjectsOfType()` like this:

```
GameObject player;
GameObject enemies;

void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
    }

void Start ()
    {
        Reinitialize ();
    }

void Update () 
    {
        if (enemies.GetComponent<EnemyGrid>().enemiesDead == true)
        {
            gameEnd = true;
        }

        if (player.GetComponent<PlayerController>().playerDead == true)
        {
            gameEnd = true;
        }
    }

void Reinitialize()
    {
        player = Object.FindObjectOfType(typeof(PlayerController)) as GameObject;
        enemies = Object.FindObjectOfType (typeof(EnemyGrid)) as GameObject;
    }
```

But there's still no object reference. My intention was to run the `Reinitialize()` funtion each time a new scene was loaded, so that way the `GameManager` would grab the new objects each time.

Comment: you may be calling reinitialize before the scene was loaded. implement the method OnLevelWasLoaded() and call reinitialize from inside of it.

Comment: Nope, it still didn't find an object reference. This is beyond me at this point. Thanks for the continued support though!

Comment: can you verify that they do exist in the scene? do they inherit from MonoBehaviour?

Comment: Yes and yes. My design was to have the `Player` and the `EnemyGrid` (in which individual enemy prefabs are instantiated) objects always in each scene from the start and `GameManager` would grab them when a scene was loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting null reference exception is normal since they were created in the previous scene and destroyed in the current one. To move them to the next scene, you need to call DontDestroyOnLoad.

Why don't you create your assets after the scene is loaded? GameManager should be responsible for creating player and enemy objects and keep track of the game state. In addition, try to use c# **event**s to communicate with the manager in order to notify events such as EnemyDestroyed or PlayerDied etc. In this way, you don't need to ask both player and enemies whether they are dead at each frame.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Yeah, I thought there might be a more optimal way to approach my problem but I was persistent to get it working "my way".

Comment: well, that's your call. it seems like you are trying to move survived enemies to the next level. as a quick fix, just call DontDestroyOnLoad for each of the objects you want to keep for the next scene. GameManager should be fine because none of the objects are going to be destroyed.

Comment: Actually no. I just wanted to have the GameManager to have `DontDestroyOnLoad()` and then when a new scene generates it would dynamically grab the references to the newly created Player and EnemyGrid objects. But I think it's a better solution just to have the GameManager create them each time a new scene is loaded. At least that way the references are not lost.

Comment: oh, I understand. did you try using GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<ComponentName>()?. I usually put placeholders to the spawn points. during level initialization, I find them using GameObject.Find() and replace with actual assets.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work... I'll edit the code to the original answer for debugging.